# Creating a DNS forward in Google Cloud Platform with Bind9

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-compute-engine, bind9

I have a DNS server which uses Bind9. I am trying to create DNS forwarding from Google's internal DNS to my nodes, which are also in the cloud.

Brief overview:

I have 3 nodes, all of them as Compute Engine in GCP. 1 node works as DNS server that has this configuration:

```
zone "gcloud" {
  type forward;
  forwarders {
    # IP according to their site https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#dns-forwarding
    169.254.169.254;
  };
};
```

I restart Bind9, everything looks good. Then on the other two nodes, I change the nameserver IP to my DNS server. When I try to use `dig` I don't get any records. Pinging the hostname worked before, but doesn't work now.

Any clue as to what am I doing wrong? Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

I thought that the name of the zone could be anything. However, that was not that case.

What I had to do was to change the name of the zone to the domain name I had. The domain look like this: `[INSTANCE_NAME].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal`. So my conf had to look like this:

```
zone "c.your-project-id-here.internal." {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders {
       169.254.169.254;
    };
};
```

Then I had to do another conf for reverse lookup. The internal IP could look something like this: `10.20.0.55`, which means you had to do reverse lookup on `20.10`.

```
zone "20.10.in-addr.arpa." {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders {
        169.254.169.254;
    };
};
```